# How to get sequential references in my paper?

Tags: bibliographies, sorting

I'm using TeXnicCenter to write all my documents and generate my bib file by using JabRef. However I noticed that my references are out of order. It seems the addition order to JabRef file forces the numbering in my file. Is there a way to see my references sequentially in my paper?

For example,

In my bib file:

> 1. Berkay et al. Using References efficiently.
> 2. Alan  et al. Asking better questions in TeX exchange.

In my tex:

> Berkay et al [2] proposed a solution for references and recently  Alan et al. [1] criticized him.

My question refers having them [1] and [2], sequentially, in order.

Comment: It's quite hard to tell from your question what the problem is, or what you're doing. Are you using `natbib`? What do you mean by 'out of order'? What order are the references in, and what order do you want them in? What kind of citation system are you using (author/year, numeric?).

Comment: @Alan Munn sorry for confusing points, edited.Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort thebibliography by citation order](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17354/sort-thebibliography-by-citation-order)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, that you want the bibliography arranged in the order that each item is first cited, then you need to write `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` or if you are using `natbib` then `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}`.

You also need to rerun latex, bibtex, latex, latex, each time the ordering of the citations changes, so as to get the changes to propagate through the .aux, .bbl files.

Comment: that's what i was looking for. Thanks +1.