# sequence number in bibliographic text how is serial number decided

Tags: bibliographies

I have a bibliography in following format
the entries in file

```
@TechReport{mell62011,
author = {Mell  Peter and Grance Timothy},
title = {Recommendations of the National Institute of Standards and Technology},
institution = {National Institute of Standards \& Technology (NIST), USA},
year = {2011},
}
@article{fernandes2014security,
  title={Security issues in cloud environments: a survey},
  author={Fernandes, Diogo AB and Soares, Liliana FB and Gomes, Jo{\~a}o V and Freire, M{\'a}rio M and In{\'a}cio, Pedro RM},
  journal={International Journal of Information Security},
  volume={13},
  number={2},
  pages={113--170},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Springer}
}
@article{de2019cyber,
  title={Cyber-Storms Come from Clouds: Security of Cloud Computing in the IoT Era},
  author={De Donno, Michele and Giaretta, Alberto and Dragoni, Nicola and Bucchiarone, Antonio and Mazzara, Manuel},
  journal={Future Internet},
  volume={11},
  number={6},
  pages={127},
  year={2019},
  publisher={Multidisciplinary Digital Publishing Institute}
}

@article{linthicum2017connecting,
  title={Connecting fog and cloud computing},
  author={Linthicum, David S},
  journal={IEEE Cloud Computing},
  volume={4},
  number={2},
  pages={18--20},
  year={2017},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
@article{shen2017block,
  title={Block design-based key agreement for group data sharing in cloud computing},
  author={Shen, Jian and Zhou, Tianqi and He, Debiao and Zhang, Yuexin and Sun, Xingming and Xiang, Yang},
  journal={IEEE Transactions on Dependable and Secure Computing},
  year={2017},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
@article{shirazi2017extended,
  title={The extended cloud: Review and analysis of mobile edge computing and fog from a security and resilience perspective},
  author={Shirazi, Syed Noorulhassan and Gouglidis, Antonios and Farshad, Arsham and Hutchison, David},
  journal={IEEE Journal on Selected Areas in Communications},
  volume={35},
  number={11},
  pages={2586--2595},
  year={2017},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
@article{kolias2017ddos,
  title={DDoS in the IoT: Mirai and other botnets},
  author={Kolias, Constantinos and Kambourakis, Georgios and Stavrou, Angelos and Voas, Jeffrey},
  journal={Computer},
  volume={50},
  number={7},
  pages={80--84},
  year={2017},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@web{fusion_analytics,
    author={Microsft},
    title={Advanced Multistage attack detection in Azure Sentinel}
    howpublished="\url{https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/fusion}"
}
@misc{microsoft,
    author = {Microsoft},
    title = {Discover and manage shadow IT in your network},
    howpublished = "\url{https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-app-security/tutorial-shadow-it}"
}
@web{microsf41,
author = {Microsoft},
title={Microsoft way of detecting threats},
howpublished="\url{https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/security-center-alerts-overview}"
}

@link{mslinks2,
author = {Microsoft},
title={Cloud Smart Alert Correlation in Azure Security Centre},
howpublished="\url{https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/security-center-alerts-cloud-smart}"
}
@link{amazon2,
author={Amazon},
title={Amazon Guard Duty},
howpublished="\url{https://aws.amazon.com/guardduty/}"
}
@link{google31,
author={Google},
title={Forsetti Intelligent Agents},
howpublished="\url{https://cloud.google.com/solutions/partners/forseti-firewall-rules-anomalies}"
}
@web{cloud33,
    author={Wikipedia},
title={Sample Cloud Image},
howpublished="\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing#/media/File:Cloud_computing.svg}"
}

@web{capgemini1,
    author={Capgemini},
title={Anomaly detection with machine learning powered by Google cloud},
howpublished="\url{https://www.capgemini.com/resources/anomaly-detection-with-machine-learning-powered-by-google-cloud/}"
}

@web{googlelab3,
    author={Google},
    title={Python data science handbook K means clustering},
    howpublished="\url{https://colab.research.google.com/github/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/05.11-K-Means.ipynb#scrollTo=JP4_e-wZJYVW}"
}
@web{google4,
    author={Google},
    title={How to view vulnerabilities and threats},
    howpublished="\url{
    https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/how-to-view-vulnerabilities-threats#dlp
    }"
}
@web{clientlibrary2,
title={Anomaly Detector Client Library for Python},
howpublished="\url{https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/anomaly-detector/quickstarts/detect-data-anomalies-python-sdk}"
}

@web{microsoft3,
    author={Microsoft},
    title={Display Anomaly Data Points},
    howpublished="\url{
    https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/anomaly-detector/tutorials/batch-anomaly-detection-powerbi
    }"
}
@article{pannu,
    author={Pannu, H.S., Liu, J.G. and Fu, S. },
    title={AAD: Adaptive Anomaly Detection System for Cloud Computing Infrastructures},

}
@article{roch,
    author={Roschke, S., Cheng, F. and Meinel, C.},
    title={ (2009) Intrusion Detection in Cloud. Eight IEEE International Conference on
    Dependable Automatic and Secure Computing, Liverpool, 729-734}
}
@article{wchen,
    author={W-H. Chen, S-H. Su, and H-P. Shen,},
    title={ “Application of svm and ann for
    intrusion detection,” Computer Oper Res, vol. 32, no.10, pp. 2617–2634,
    2005}
}

@article{dhanl,
    author={Y. Dhanalakshmi, and I. Ramesh Babu},
    title={“Intrusion detection using data
    mining along fuzzy logic and genetic algorithms,”}
    journal={International Journal
    of Computer Science \& Security},
    volume=  {8},
    issue={2},
    pages= {27–32}, 
    year={2008}
}
@web{density,
    author={Daniel Chepenko},
    title={A density based algorithm for outlier detection},
    howpublished="\url{https://towardsdatascience.com/density-based-algorithm-for-outlier-detection-8f278d2f7983}"
}
```

when I get to see final pdf generated then it is as following
[image: references image]

if you note reference number 2 is the last number in the bibliography pasted above I expected this to be last reference in the pdf generated.
So I want to know how is this 1,2,3,4 generated,
which thing in my bibliography is getting priority

```
@Techreport,@article,@web,@link,@misc,
```

these are the tags I used I did it at random what ever came to my mind.
Is there a systematic nomencleature for this.

I am using a template which I downloaded from here https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/eusflat-2019-template/jmqvcrhkqhgx
I downloaded in my local machine and I am using it.

There is a file with name EUSFLAT2019_template.bbl I see following in it

```
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\expandafter\ifx\csname url\endcsname\relax
  \def\url#1{\texttt{#1}}\fi
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlprefix\endcsname\relax\def\urlprefix{URL }\fi
```

then I see a lot of \bibitem entries in it.
Then I have BIBeusflat2019.bib in which I have all these things in format

```
@web{density,
    author={Daniel Chepenko},
    title={A density based algorithm for outlier detection},
    howpublished="\url{https://towardsdatascience.com/density-based-algorithm-for-outlier-detection-8f278d2f7983}"
}
```

Comment: Looks like your bibliography has been alphabetized.  You don't give us enough information to tell us what bibliography style you are using.

Comment: The order in which the references are mentioned in the .bib file is not related to the order in which they appear in the list of references. How they are sorted here depends on the bibliography stale used. Often, references are sorted alphabeticaly or by appearance.

Comment: I am using a template shared here https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/eusflat-2019-template/jmqvcrhkqhgx I downloaded it and using it on my local machine

Comment: Please double check the syntax of the entries of your bib file. At least the last 4 are definitely not correct. Authors should be separated by "and" and journal names, years and page numbers do not belong into the title field.

Comment: I recommend using a style that lists citations in the order of usage *and then*, at the beginning of the document, issuing the command, `\setbox0=\hbox{\cite{aaa,bbb,...}}`, where `aaa,bbb,...` is the preferred order in which you would like the future references to occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've already sorted your bib file, you can try to use \bibliographystyle{unsrt}.
**Src:** [Sort thebibliography by citation order](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17354/sort-thebibliography-by-citation-order)

Comment: But this will sort the bibliography in the order in which the references are cited in the document, not i the order in which they are mentioned in the bib file?

Comment: I am using a template   It has a `.bib` file, I want to know where should I put  `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` as mentioned on your answer meaning in which file I should put it , this is the template link https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/eusflat-2019-template/jmqvcrhkqhgx

Comment: @leandriis I know of no style that will sort according to the order of the bib file.  From a LaTeX point of view, the order in the bib file is (I think) wholly irrelevant to the way in which bibliography sorting occurs.

Comment: @StevenBSegletes: I totally agree with you.

Comment: there are two files BIBeusflat2019.bib and EUSFLAT2019_template.bbl I think I have been editing a lot of entries and added them somehow in BIBeusflat2019.bib but the order in which they are coming are from EUSFLAT2019_template.bbl the entry which is first in EUSFLAT2019_template.bbl file is coming first and so on.

Comment: @leandriis At the end of your .tex file you should already have a "\bibliographystyle" you can just replace the text.  And my solution does not automatically sort by appearance. The references will appear as they are sorted on you .bib file.

Comment: in the file EUSFLAT2019_template.tex at the end I had 
\bibliographystyle{eusflat2019} I commented this by adding a % and then it becomes 
%\bibliographystyle{eusflat2019} and added following 
\bibliographystyle{unsrt} in the same file but there was no effect on the serial order of bibliographic references.

Comment: @GuilyPin: Run the following minimal example and you will see that your claim " references will appear as they are sorted on you .bib file"  is definitely not correct when using the `unsrt` bibliography style. References will instead be sorted by the order in which you cite them using `\cite`. Here is the [output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78zGs.png). As you can see, "first in bib"  comes last in the bibliography although it is the first entry in the bib file.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{keyfirst,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {first in bib},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@book{keysecond,
  author = {Author, B.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {second in bib},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{keysecond}
\cite{keyfirst}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}`

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` in file EUSFLAT2019_template.tex but there was also a line `\bibliographystyle{eusflat2019}` so I let these 2 remain as

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliographystyle{eusflat2019}
```

compiled pdf there was no effect on citations. The citations came unsorted i.e. not in the order of appearance. 
Then I tried putting `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` in `BIBeusflat2019.bib` there was no effect the citations did not came in sorted order.
Then I also tried putting 
`\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` before 
`\begin{thebibliography}{10}` but there was no effect
so finally I tried following

There is a file 
EUSFLAT2019_template.bbl
The order in which the references appear in this same is the order in which it appear in final pdf. So I copied all the content of this file on notepad and then I went to original tex file I did a Ctrl+F and searched for `\cite{` so I got the first citation which should appear first so I copied the item in the file EUSFLAT2019_template.bbl from which ever position it was to top order. Then I did a Ctrl+F and again searched `\cite{` I got second citation then in the bbl file I copied corresponding item to 2nd location and so on I repeated this process.
then I got citations in the order in which I had cited them.I have saved a text file of this bibliography so that when I edit it in future and I get an error of this sort
[image: error in desktop]
I have a backup sorted copy of bibliography and I can manually go and sort all the items.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\expandafter\ifx\csname url\endcsname\relax
  \def\url#1{\texttt{#1}}\fi
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlprefix\endcsname\relax\def\urlprefix{URL }\fi

\bibitem{amazon2}
Amazon, Amazon guard duty, \url{https://aws.amazon.com/guardduty/}.

\bibitem{cloudwatch}
Amazon, What is amazon 

\bibitem{capgemini1}
Capge,google-cloud/}.

\bibitem{CHEN20052617}
W.-H. Chen, S.-H. Hsu, 
\bibitem{density}
D.~Chepenko, A density 8f278d2f7983}.

\bibitem{dhanl}
Y.~Dhanalakshmi, Ic algorithms.

\bibitem{google31}
Google, firewall-rules-anomalies}.

\bibitem{fusion_analytics}
Microsoft, sentinel/fusion}.

\bibitem{mslinks2}
Microsoft, security-center-alerts-cloud-smart}.

\bibitem{microsoft}
Microsoft, security/tutorial-shadow-it}.

\bibitem{microsf41}
Microsoft, enter-alerts-overview}.

\bibitem{pannu}
L.~J. Pannu, nfrastructures.

\bibitem{roch}
S.~{Roschke}, F.~{Cheng}, C.~{Meinel}, Intrusion detection in the cloud, in:

\end{thebibliography}
```

The final pdf has the citations in the order in which they were cited.

I also want to add on that while upto the steps above did worked for me and the pdf generated had desired output. 
Later on I tried following also
In the file BIBeusflat2010.bib the citation entries i.e. putting these entries in citation order from the paper.So this also seems to work as desired. But before you do all this just copy all the work you did in another folder so that you have a backup in case any thing goes wrong and then make all changes. I have now also made a github account and I struggled a lot on github to setup my project.

```
@web{density,
    author = {Daniel Chepenko},
    title = {A density based algorithm for outlier detection},
    howpublished="\url{https://towar83}",
}
@misc{microsoft,
    author = {Microsoft},
    title = {Discover and manage shadow IT in your network},
    howpublished = "\url{htow-it}"
}

@web{microsf41,
    author = {Microsoft},
    title={Microsoft way of detecting threats},
    howpublished="\url{httpverview}"
}
```

Also the template I am using based on a comment [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532805/misplaced-alignment-tab-in-a-reference-eusflat2019-template#comment1347249_532806) it appears 
"the bibliography style you are using (.bst file) sorts the bibliography entries that way. To change that you need to use another bibliography style."
I do not know how to use sorting in bibliography styles. So that people like me who come at last moment seeking help are able to understand.
The template I use is https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/eusflat-2019-template/jmqvcrhkqhgx
I will update this answer in future if I am able to find more information.

Comment: So to sum it up, you did the whole thing manually and without the help of any useful tools. In fact, using any useful tool now will destroy your manual work.

Comment: For other readers or for future you: It is an error to have more than one `\bibliographystyle` in a document (with the standard setup). BibTeX will complain about that. You can only have one `\bibliographystyle` in your `.tex` file (it can be placed in the preamble or in the document body). The command will have no (useful) effect anywhere else.

Comment: @Johannes_B yes I experienced that situation in subsequent edits so I have made a file in notepad `bibliography text 28-3-2020.txt` and saved all the sorted entries into it. So if in future some thing happens I can copy paste the entries from it back to original file and I will keep regularly updating this text file so that I don't fall back in a situation to sort things again and again. Also I uploaded a version of all my work in github so that I can download things back to previous if I fall in some mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I used `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}` to custom BibTeX style for formatting the Bibliography. And it worked.