# How to make bibliography in order of reference

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I use BibTex for my bibliography and I would like to make my references listed in order of their citation but also use the acm format.

If that doesn't work, how does one use the abbreviations references in order of their citation?

Comment: Use `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}.  This is a duplicate: [Sort thebibliography by citation order](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17354)

Answer (score 0):

Use `biblatex` with these options `\usepackage[style=ACM-Reference-Format,backend=bibtex,sorting=none]{biblatex}`.

More info can be found at [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex?lang=en).

Comment: The OP mentioned he uses BibTex.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it will solve your problem:

```
%...

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bibli}

\end{document}
```

So Instead of

> \bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}

Use this style:

> \bibliographystyle{unsrt}