# Change Citation Numbering to Consecutive Numbers in LaTeX Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, citing, bibliographystyle

How can I change the appearance of the \cite{} command in my LaTeX document so that the citations appear as consecutive numbers (e.g., 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.) instead of the default numbering? Currently, my citations are appearing as 7, 4, 5, etc., which is not the desired format. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\begin{document}
According to \cite{7}, \cite{6}, \cite{3}, \cite{1}, \cite{2}
\bigskip
    \begin{thebibliography}{9}
        \bibitem{1} Educ 1
        \bibitem{2} Educ 2 
        \bibitem{3} Educ 3
        \bibitem{4} Educ 4
        \bibitem{5} Educ 5
        \bibitem{6} Educ 6 
        \bibitem{7} Educ 7 
    \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

which produces :

[image]

but i desired this style if possible:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `cite` package to sort consecutive citations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sort,nocompress]{cite}
\begin{document}
According to \cite{7,6,3,1,2}
\bigskip
    \begin{thebibliography}{9}
        \bibitem{1} Educ 1
        \bibitem{2} Educ 2 
        \bibitem{3} Educ 3
        \bibitem{4} Educ 4
        \bibitem{5} Educ 5
        \bibitem{6} Educ 6 
        \bibitem{7} Educ 7 
    \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but when I use `\cite{7}, \cite{6}, \cite{3}, \cite{1}, \cite{2}` instead of `\cite{7,6,3,1,2}`, the change doesn't apply.

Comment: @Educ If you split the citation into individual macros, the cite package can't change the order, then it is your responsibility to order them.

Comment: is there any other way to order them automatically ?

Comment: You could use bibtex or biblatex and order the references by appearance, but this will change the order in the bibliography, too.

Comment: @Educ If changing the order in the bibliography is ok (although your second sceenshot uses the same order in the bibliography than the first one), then have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17354/sort-thebibliography-by-citation-order