# References not ordered

Tags: citing

[2] is my third citation, and others looks like this.

[image]

I expect something like [3][4][5][6][7][8]

I use jabref. How could I resolve this?

I am aware of this  [How to get sequential references in my paper?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14976/how-to-get-sequential-references-in-my-paper) however I haven't gotten it. Someone could give more details to fix this. [svjour] is a springer class

```
\begin{filecontents}{magenta.eps}
gsave
newpath
20 20 moveto
20 220 lineto
220 220 lineto
220 20 lineto
closepath
2 setlinewidth
gsave
.4 setgray fill
grestore
stroke
grestore
\end{filecontents}
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
\smartqed  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[linesnumbered, ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}    

\title{How X affects Y}
\maketitle

Research works like \cite{ade2011determine}\cite{baj2011acoustic}\cite{fui2011energy}\cite{gardy2006energy}\cite{guang2007energy}\cite{kahmati2007energy}

\bibliography{ref} 
\end{document}
```

For example, this is the first three of the citations above in the ref.bib file (ref.bib is in the same folder with the .tex file)
Please note: I observed the citations are ordered in the output the same way they are ordered in the .bib file. Also, entries in ref.bib is ordered alphabetically. I would like to order them in "chronologically" in terms of its position of citation. A sample content of the .bib file is shown below. There are a few references (not from the ones cited) in between (but I have tried to conserve space)

```
@InProceedings{ade...,
Title                    = {deter XXXXXXXXXXXXX},
Author                   = {Ade, xxx and xxxxx},
Booktitle                = {XXXXXXXXXXXX},
Year                     = {2001},
Organization             = {XXX},
Pages                    = {1--3}
}
@Article{baj...,
Title                    = {Acoustic xxxxx},
Author                   = {Baj, xxxx and xxx, xxxx},
Journal                  = {Journal of xxxxxxx},
Year                     = {2011},
Number                   = {1},
Pages                    = {82--92},
Volume                   = {72},

@InProceedings{gui....,
Title                    = {Energy xxxxxx},
Author                   = {gui, x and xxx, x},
Booktitle                = {International Conference on xxxxxx },
Year                     = {2011}
}

Publisher                = {XXXXX}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: For ordering your citation you could use the [cite-package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cite).

Comment: This comes probably from your references being sorted alphabetically. If you use 'biblatex' you can pass the option 'sorting=none' to the  package so that the references are simply put in the order they are cited.

Comment: I have the .bbl file. Although, I use jabref, how do I pass the command. Thanks @Enno

Comment: To get sorted refs. they all need to be in the argument to a _single_ `\cite`: `\cite{RefA,RefB, ...}`.

Comment: That edit was not helpful at all.